# Find AB_CSRS.gsb for NAD_1983_TO_WGS_1984_8 Transformation

Tags: arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, datum, canada

I am trying to change my WGS84 data to NAD83 for Alberta data. My research tells me that I need to use the NAD_1983_TO_WGS_1984_8 Datum Transformation which is in the AB_CSRS.gsb. I can not find this gsb file for download on the internet. I did manage to find and obtain the NTv2_0.GSB but that seems to only be for NAD27 To NAD83.

Does anyone know where I can get the AB_CSRS.GSB file?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AB_CSRS file seems to have been replaced with abcsrsv4.dac. Esri hasn't added another transformation to use the new file yet (we don't have a copy). You could rename it and use the NAD_1983_To_WGS_1984_8 transformation, or create a new transformation with the geoprocessing tool, [Create Custom Geographic Transformation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Create_Custom_Geographic_Transformation/001700000076000000/). You will still have to change the extension from .dac to .gsb.

I wasn't able to find information about the file on the Alberta Geodetic Control Unit website, but others have said to contact the director, [Geoff Banham](http://alberta.ca/albertaFiles/includes/DirectorySearch/browse_view.cfm?txtSearch=geoff%20banham&item=28951&x=0#28951).

Note: I work for Esri.

Comment: I have emailed Geoff Banham and he was very helpful in sending me the ABCSRS4.DAC. This file needs to be placed in the C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\pedata\ntv2\canada folder (For my computer) and renamed to AB_CSRS.GSB to work. Now the NAD_1983_To_WGS_1984_8 transformation shows up when I run the Project tool.

Comment: I found Geoff Banham's email here http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geomatics/geodetic-reference-systems/canadian-spatial-reference-system/9112